# Spring Security SAML Extension and @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-saml

My requirements are to use SAML based SSO. Retrieve the user groups from SAML assertions and secure the rest api endpoints. I am using Spring security SAML extension and Spring MVC. The steps I have taken are.

1. Configure the application for SP using Spring SAML extension. [Done]
2. Retrieve assertions and assign roles [Done]
3. Create rest endpoint. [Done]
4. Secure rest endpoint and services based on roles. [Not working]

I have implemented SAMLUserDetailsService which returns a UserDetails object with authorities. 'loadUserBySAML' below.

```
@Override
public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential credential) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    final String userId = credential.getNameID().getValue();

    final String emailAddress = credential.getAttributeAsString("EmailAddress");
    final String firstName = credential.getAttributeAsString("FirstName");
    final String lastName = credential.getAttributeAsString("LastName");

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_STUDENT"));

    return new User(userId, emailAddress, firstName, lastName, authorities);
}
```

I have added `<!-- Enable security annotations on methods -->
    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />`to the securityContext.xml.

On the RestController and on the services I am using @PreAuthorize but this annotation seems to have no effect at all.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_PROGRAMLEAD')")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String hello() {
    return "Hello.";}
```

Could someone please help me understand why the PreAuthorize is not firing? Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I wanted to perform API authorisation with SAML authentication. For it to work, you need to use the `hasAuthority` param with the annotation instead of the `hasRole` param.
The following worked for me:

```
@PreAuthorize(value="hasAuthority('Admin')")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />` needs to go in the servlet xml of the rest controller and not the security context xml.

Reference: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context